# Where did all the space go on my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 74.4 SSD drive.  Disk Properties tell me that it has around 2 GB left.

[image]

However, if you add up all the files & folders, only ~ 60 GB is taken up.  Where are the other 14 GB?

[image]

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? There could be a pagefile.sys, a hiberfil.sys and/or swapfile.sys in the root of C: (hidden and as system). Also... the access to the "System Volume Information" seems to be denied. So the remaining 14GB would probably be in there :)

Comment: It has 8 GB of RAM.  What app do you recommend I use in order to get an accurate breakdown of my hard drive?

Comment: @Rik's got it, You're not running TreeSize "as administrator", so you'll be denied access to several folders, therefore not being able to enumerate the contents.

Comment: You didn't run the application as an Administrator.  Says so right in your screenshot.   Your space is used by the shadow service to recover previously versions of files and restoration points